# How can i fetch multiple list data to single screen in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a quiz app in flutter which has multiple subjects in grid view. Each grid redirect to a screen which fetch data from a list one by one.
What I want to do : Whenever I click to a grid view, it redirect me to a single screen and fetch data from the respective list.

I want to go to a single screen whenever I click on the grid view but it should show data from the list with respect to grid view user click.

[Grid view example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxWgb.png)

This is grid view example and each number represent a different subject.

```html
final first = const [
  {
    'question': 'How long is New Zealand’s Ninety Mile Beach?',
    'answers': [
      {'answerText': '88km, so 55 miles long.', 'score': true},
      {'answerText': '55km, so 34 miles long.', 'score': false},
      {'answerText': '90km, so 56 miles long.', 'score': false},
    ],
  },
  {
    'question':
        'In which month does the German festival of Oktoberfest mostly take place?',
    'answers': [
      {'answerText': 'January', 'score': false},
      {'answerText': 'October', 'score': false},
      {'answerText': 'September', 'score': true},
    ],
  },
  {
    'question': 'Who composed the music for Sonic the Hedgehog 3?',
    'answers': [
      {'answerText': 'Britney Spears', 'score': false},
      {'answerText': 'Timbaland', 'score': false},
      {'answerText': 'Michael Jackson', 'score': true},
    ],
  },
];



final second = const [
{
    'question': 'In Georgia (the state), it’s illegal to eat what with a fork?',
    'answers': [
      {'answerText': 'Hamburgers', 'score': false},
      {'answerText': 'Fried chicken', 'score': true},
      {'answerText': 'Pizza', 'score': false},
    ],
  },
  {
    'question':
        'Which part of his body did musician Gene Simmons from Kiss insure for one million dollars?',
    'answers': [
      {'answerText': 'His tongue', 'score': true},
      {'answerText': 'His leg', 'score': false},
      {'answerText': 'His butt', 'score': false},
    ],
  },
  {
    'question': 'In which country are Panama hats made?',
    'answers': [
      {'answerText': 'Ecuador', 'score': true},
      {'answerText': 'Panama (duh)', 'score': false},
      {'answerText': 'Portugal', 'score': false},
    ],
  },
  {
    'question': 'From which country do French fries originate?',
    'answers': [
      {'answerText': 'Belgium', 'score': true},
      {'answerText': 'France', 'score': false},
      {'answerText': 'Switzerland', 'score': false},
    ],
  },
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code with a gesture detector.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.count(
      // Create a grid with 2 columns. If you change the scrollDirection to
      // horizontal, this produces 2 rows.
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      mainAxisSpacing: 20,
      crossAxisSpacing: 20,
      // Generate 100 widgets that display their index in the List.
      children: List.generate(5, (index) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => NewQuestionPage(
                      questionId: index.toString(),
                    )));
          },
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            height: 100,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'Item $index',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
    ;
  }
}

class NewQuestionPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? questionId;

  const NewQuestionPage({Key? key, this.questionId}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Questions"),
      ),
      body: Center(child: Text(questionId!)),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how should I fetch data from different lists for example we have two list named first and second.

Comment: please share the list so I can understand.